# Initial conditions of experimental units in Completely Randomized Design

Tags: anova, experiment-design, random-allocation

Since I had no answer to the second part of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20414/balance-between-randomization-interspersion-and-even-initial-conditions-of-expe) question I would like to ask it again providing some more infos I gathered in the meantime.

**Context**
We are designing a complete randomized trial in a forest. The plots (experimental units) exhibit natural variability in the response variables. Since we will set up 3 replicates for each of the 3 treatments we only have 9 plots and, depending on the random configuration of assignment of treatments to them, the initial conditions, as far as the response variables are concerned, can be significantly different.
In an effort to guarantee similar initial conditions, we have computed ANOVAs for all the possible initial configurations and selected a subset of only those whose $F$ statistic $\approx1$, thus equally partitioning total variance between and within groups. In our ED, for $F\approx1$, $p\approx0.42$: well above the conventional limit $\alpha=0.05$ needed for the rejection of null hyphotesis of no difference between treatments.
The actual configuration would then be randomly selected from the subset of $F\approx 1$ configurations.

**Question**
The $F\approx1$ is an arbitrary threshold but one that makes much more sense than, for example, minimizing $F$, a strategy that would maximize variance within groups resembling a Randomized Complete Block design, without blocks!
Are there specific experiences in assuring similar initial conditions between experimental units? Do you reckon the $F\approx1$ *criterium* is feasible?

Comment: Why not use the initial condition as a blocking factor (lower, middle, upper third) and set it up as a randomized complete block design?

Comment: Thank you onestop. We discarded RCB design because the blocking factors we evaluated in simulation studies proved not to extract enough MS for the degrees of freedom we lost by blocking...

Comment: Your setup seems reasonable to me, but I do think @onestop is on to something--perhaps there's another way.  Could you record initial conditions and then run your analysis using change scores?  (I.e., $Y_{i,t=1}-Y_{i,t=0}$.)

Comment: Yes, definitely. Scores will augment probability of telling apart treatment effect. The problem is that initial values will not be available for all response variables and that's the reason I would like to ensure similar initial conditions.